# I have a questions regarding matlab matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix

### Suppose I have this matrix:

```
m=[1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 8 9]
```

### I want this matrix in MATLAB:

```
a=[1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3;1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3;4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6;4,4,4,5,5,5,6,6,6;7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9;7,7,7,8,8,8,9,9,9]
```

### Please help to make this matrix,

### Thanks in advance,

Comment: What does the second matrix have to do with the first?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I like the kronecker tensor product

```
m=[1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 8 9];
a = kron(m,ones(2,3))
```

each element in `a` is a product between the current element in `m` and the matrix in the second argument (which would be clear if the second argument contains other values than `1`). But this would do for your example

Answer (score 1):

This may be faster than using a Kronecker product:

```
m = [1 2 3;4 5 6; 7 8 9]; %// data
rep = [2 3]; %// number of repetitions of rows and columns respectively

a = m(ceil((1:size(m,1)*rep(1))/rep(1)), ceil((1:size(m,2)*rep(2))/rep(2)));
```

Comment: Well got a point there. If time is an issue, this may be preferred. Otherwise, the kronecker product more readable. +1